# WordPress URL rewriting in functions.php

Tags: wordpress

I need the URL's to look like this:

```
http://localhost/TestProjects/wordpress/gmat/resources etc.
```

I wrote the below function in my functions.php file of my theme folder

```
add_action('init', 'custom_rewrite_basic');
function custom_rewrite_basic() {
    $rcat='(gmat|gre|sat|cat)';
    add_rewrite_tag( '%rootcat%',$rcat);
    add_rewrite_rule('^{$rcat}/resources/', 'index.php?    pagename=leap_resources&rootcat=$matches[1]', 'top');
}
```